# Prevent swipe scroll in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a normal JQuery Mobile app and I'm trying to build a custom dialog that places a semi-opaque black mask over the UI and then centers a dialog on the screen.

My widget works as expected, except the user can swipe on my mask to scroll the page hidden behind the dialog.  I added the CSS pointer-events: none to it, but apparently that doesn't do it.

Is there another way to intercept the swipe/scroll and cancel it?

Comment: If the div fills the screen as has z-index higher than the UI elements, then it should work. Providing a fiddle would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).bind("touchmove",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Should work. Not sure how this will behave with jquery-mobile though.